# Transform list of objects {string, list-of-strings} into a stream of strings like "main1 sub1", "main1 sub2", "main2 sub3"

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I have a list of objects of the Category class.

```
class Category { 
  String main;
  List<String> subs;
}
```

How I can transform a list of Category objects into a stream of Strings in this format:

```
cat-0 sub-0-0
cat-0 sub-0-1
...
cat-2 sub-2-3
```

Requested is a complete, but short example.

```
public class Category {
  String main;
  List<String> subs = new ArrayList<>();

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Category> categories = new ArrayList<>();
    for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      Category cat = new Category();
      cat.main = "cat-" + i;
      for( int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        cat.subs.add( "sub-" + i + "-" + j);
      }
      categories.add( cat);
    }
    categories.stream()
      .flatMap( ???).forEach( x -> System.out.println( x));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stream over `subs` and transform into your format and flatten the list.

```
listOfcategories.stream()
                .flatMap(c -> c.getSubs().stream().map(s -> c.getMain() + " " + s))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Very nice answer! Thank you so much.